# Interpolation using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, interpolation

I want to do cubic spline interpolation with QGIS (3.6), but:

Why the result of interpolation is not a polygon?

And interpolation don't cover all country?

(see attached picture)?

[image]

Comment: The saga algorithm is a raster creation tool, so the result is a raster. you can use polygonize with the result to get a vector layer. the edges are not intepolated due to the distribution of your points. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation for more information

Comment: @eurojam that seems like a perfectly valid answer

Answer (score 2):

The saga algorithm is a raster creation tool, so the result is a raster. you can use polygonize with the result to get a vector layer. the edges are not intepolated due to the distribution of your points. see en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation for more information